# Do archaea undergo the same horizontal gene transfer processes as bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, taxonomy, horizontal-gene-transfer

Do archaea also undergo processes like conjugation, trasformation, etc.? If not, do they have their own horizontal gene transfer methods? Can bacteria conjugate with archaea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagner A, Whitaker RJ, Krause DJ, Heilers JH, van Wolferen M, van der Does C, Albers SV (2017) *Mechanisms of gene flow in archaea.* Nat Rev Microbiol 15: [492-501](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28502981).

> **The exchange of genetic material** is a major driving force for genome
>   evolution across the tree of life and has a role in **archaeal
>   speciation, adaptation and maintenance of diversity.**

---

Soucy SM, Huang J, Gogarten JP (2015) *Horizontal gene transfer: building the web of life.* Nat Rev Genet 16: [472-482](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26184597).

> **Horizontal gene transfer (HGT)** is the sharing of genetic material between organisms that are not in a parent-offspring relationship. HGT
>   is a widely recognized mechanism for adaptation **in bacteria and
>   archaea.**

---

Fuchsman CA, Collins RE, Rocap G, Brazelton WJ (2017) *Effect of the environment on horizontal gene transfer between bacteria and archaea.* PeerJ 29: [e3865](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28975058).

> Potential hotspots of **horizontal gene transfer between archaea and
>   bacteria** include hot springs, marine sediments, and oil wells.

Comment: I think the OP was addressing the mechanics behind HGT of archaea, not just "is there such a thing".

Comment: @LinuxBlanket: My answer has both.

Comment: Your answer is "yes, there is HGT in archaea and it's important", not "archaea do HGT by conjugation and not by Y or Z". This information may be contained in one of the references, but *not* in your answer.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket: The references, and references therein, are also parts of the answer.